# Bash - rename 'Image (x).png' files

Tags: bash

I had a bunch of windows scan files, e.g. `Image.png`, `Image (2).png`, `...` `Image (19).png`.

I needed to rename these to `Image01.png` `...` `Image19.png` so I could then throw them at an `imagemagick` convert command to paginate them in order into an output pdf.

This was the command I ended up using:

`ls * | awk '{print "mv \""$0"\" \"2"$0"2\"" }' | sed -e 's/2Image (/Image0/' | sed -e 's/).png2/.png/' | sed -e 's/[0-9]\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1/' | sed -e 's/2Image.png2/Image01.png/' | sh`

This worked, but there much be a more concise way of doing it, that doesn't involve using dirty/buggy placeholders like inserting random `2` characters to make the rename work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rename 's/^Image\.png$/Image01.png/ || s/^Image\s+\((\d+)\)\.png$/sprintf "%s%02d.png", "Image", $1/e' *.png
```

---

### Method

- The `rename` utility is the way to go in your scenario. It's working model is the following: takes a list of filenames and applies a valid `Perl` transform on each filename and what comes out of the transform becomes the new name of the filename.
- s/^Image.png$/Image(01).png/ => this is for tackling the Image.png file.
- s/^Image\s+((\d+)).png$/ => match a filename beginning with Image then any amount of one or more spaces followed by a literal opening bracket ( and one or more digits \d+ and a closing bracket ) and ending with the .png.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the files are called `Image.png` and `Image (2).png` though to `Image (19).png`, there is no need for regular expressions:

```
mv Image.png Image01.png
for i in {2..19}; do
    zi=$( printf '%02d' "$i" )
    mv "Image ($i).png" "Image$zi.png"
done
```

`$zi` will be a zero-filled two character wide integer version of `$i`.